# Fill Empty cells from the below row values in r

Tags: r

I have data as below

```
col1  col2  col3


56    78    89

67     76   43
```

I want to fill the empty cells as below in r

```
col1  col2  col3
56    78    89        
56    78    89        
56    78    89
67    76    43    
67    76    43
```

Comment: Do you have first two cells empty?  Try `library(zoo); df1[df1==""] <- NA;df1[] <- lapply(df1, na.locf, fromLast=TRUE)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to change the blank cells (`""`) to `NA` and then use `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(na.locf(replace(x, x=="", NA), fromLast=TRUE)))
df1
#  col1 col2 col3
#1   56   78   89
#2   56   78   89
#3   56   78   89
#4   67   76   43
#5   67   76   43
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("", "", "56", "", "67"), col2 = c("", 
 "", "78", "", "76"), col3 = c("", "", "89", "", "43")), .Names = c("col1", 
 "col2", "col3"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with `fill` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%
  fill(names(.), .direction = "up")
```

**Result:**

```
  col1 col2 col3
1   56   78   89
2   56   78   89
3   56   78   89
4   67   76   43
5   67   76   43
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(col1 = c("", "", "56", "", "67"), col2 = c("", 
"", "78", "", "76"), col3 = c("", "", "89", "", "43")), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2", "col3"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```